Projection into metric spaces
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $M\subseteq X$. What could be a projection $X$ onto $M$? Is there any way to define this generally?
I saw that it can be defined like this: The projection
$P: X \to M$ is defined as follows:
$$P(x) = \arg \min_{m \in M} d(x, m)$$
This means that for a given point $x \in X$, $P(x)$ is the point $m \in M$ such that the distance $d(x, m)$ is minimized. If there are multiple points in $M$ that achieve the minimum distance, the projection may not be unique, and in such cases, $P(x)$ can return any one of those points or all of them.
But can it really be defined that way in general? I wanted something that always behaved like this: $P^2=P$.
Thanks for the help!

You have answered the question yourself? How do I project the real number $0$ to ${+1,-1}$? How do I project the real number $0$ to ${1/n : n > 1}$?

@MartinBrandenburg the projection is not unique. But is there any generic definition? Or does it really depend on space?

@MartinBrandenburgI wanted something that always behaved like this: $P^2=P$

I think what you're looking for is a retract. It's defined topologically so includes metric spaces as a subcase. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)

@CyclotomicField Ah, that's exactly it, thank you very much!

As pointed out in the comments, a mapping of the kind you want is called a retraction. The nearest point mapping doesn't provide a retraction in general: as you point out it may not be unique, but also it may not exist: e.g., take $X = [0, 1]$ and $M = (0, 1]$: there is no point in $M$ that minimises the distance to $0$.
If $X = \Bbb{R}$ and $M = \{-1, +1\}$, then no retraction of $X$ onto $M$ exists, because there is no continuous surjection of $X$ onto $M$ (because $X$ is connected and $M$ is not, while a continuous image of a connected set is connected).
You might conjecture that the above counterexamples can be outlawed by requiring $M$ to be compact and connected. Alas this does not work: if you take $X = \Bbb{C}$ (the complex plane) and $M = S^1 = \{ z \mid |z|= 1\}$ (the unit circle). $M$ cannot be a retract of $X$. It requires a bit of algebraic topology to prove this: if $M$ were a retract of $X$, then the fundamental group $\pi_1(M)$ would be a quotient of the fundamental group  $\pi_1(X)$, but $\pi_1(M) \simeq \Bbb{Z}$ while $\pi_1(X) \simeq 0$.
